# Camel normalizer bean not registered

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, integration-patterns

I'm trying to implement a normalizer the way it's written here:
http://camel.apache.org/normalizer.html

I'm getting this exception:

```
org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for
: normalizer
```

My .configure() in the RouteBuilder looks like this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    JndiContext context = new JndiContext();
    context.bind("normalizer", new MyNormalizer());

    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(context);
    camelContext.addRoutes(this);

    from("activemq:queue:input.splitter")
            .split().tokenizeXML("person").streaming()
            .to("activemq:queue:output.splitter");

    from("activemq:queue:input.normalizer")
            .choice()
            .when().xpath("//persons/person/position").to("bean:normalizer?method=positionChange")
            .end()
            .to("activemq:queue:output.normalizer");

}
```

The normalizer looks like this:

```
public class MyNormalizer {
    public void positionChange(Exchange exchange, @XPath("//persons/person/position") String name) {
        exchange.getOut().setBody(createPerson(name));
    }

    private String createPerson(String name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I found one solution about adding that piece of code into the RouteBuilder:

```
JndiContext context = new JndiContext();
context.bind("normalizer", new MyNormalizer());

CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(context);
```

But it didn't give any result.
So what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found.
The bean has to be specified in the conf/camel.xml.
In my case the definition looks like this:

```
<bean name="normalizer" id="normalizer" class="com.myroute.route.normalizer.MyNormalizer"/>
```

Comment: Yea, you need to register the bean. You could either do that in your xml if you are using xml config or you could that in your java configuration class.